# FB.ui dialog "permissions_request" callback never called?

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, dialog

I've made a successful FB.init() and am calling FB.ui to display a nice App request from within a page tab.

I am doing this as the following:

```
FB.ui({
 method: 'permissions_request',
 perms: 'some,permissions,i,need',
 redirect_uri: '',
 display: 'iframe'
 }, 
function(response){
 alert(response);
});
```

The permissions are - of course - other ones.
However: the dialog gets displayed and looks good! My only problem is, that my defined callback function never gets called -.-

I have taken my setup for the dialog from: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Dialog:permissions.request

Comment: Okay, my solution until I found something better is starting an interval and constantly check FB.getLoginStatus() with request force set to true until the state switched to "connected". This works for now, except that I never will get a chance to see if the user has declined the dialog ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    yourFunction();
}
, { scope : 'manage_pages' });
```

change manage_pages to some permissions that you need :)

Comment: No, this opens ugly popups in new browser windows. I want to use the FB.ui dialog because it blends into facebook real nice.